# Explicitly a "Stack Overflow is NOT a forum" warning when the word "forum" is used

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have increasingly seen new and some existing users refer to "is this the right forum" for this question, especially their discussion/recommendation type questions.

They usually make a token effort to *appear* they intend to do "right" but only read enough of the help to know things get closed but not what or why, basically a lazy pre-emptive *don't close this, just give me an answer as quickly as possible* attempt.

> This is the same as apologising about throwing trash on the floor is
>   just acknowledging and justifying what you are doing instead of
>   finding the trashcan.

Then they complain about people being mean when things get closed because they put discussion like responses in the answer boxes and refuse to up date questions with more information and instead just spam the comments with code blocks.

I think we can more proactively correct this with some simple reminders/warnings.

Comment: Well, you could always (re-)direct them to _The Tour_ in a comment, down and close vote the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I assume Jarrod want to prevent  that the OP gets that kind of reception ....

Comment: spot-check suggests [high false positive rate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=forum+is%3Aquestion+created%3A30d..)

Comment: This sounds to me more like a pet-peeve than anything. While I get the whole "stack isn't a forum"..... it is, when you look at what defines a forum. In ANY case, when "forum" is used as "site".... is it really a matter that they use "forum", or is the deeper problem that they knowingly send trash our way? Remove "forum", they'll use "place". Remove "place", they'll use "site", etc etc etc (remember how homework questions became "I got this in an interview"?)This won't help with the underlying behavior, IMHO

Comment: If people don't read the tour, I doubt they care about the differences between Q&A and a forum.  And well-meaning people will probably only mess up the "forum" aspect (like posting comments as answers) once after someone corrects them.

Comment: Here is a forum style question about building a forum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36542190/basic-forum-functionality

Comment: Agree with @Patrice. To most people, "forum" = "a place where people meet to talk about a problem or issue". Correcting them with a reminder is going to sound a bit childish, and it certainly isn't going to make those who don't get our model suddenly understand it and become good citizens.

Comment: On Meta, by the way, the feature is implemented already in the form of Meta users who are always sure to rise to the occasion when someone uses the f-word.

Comment: Are you sure? Is it really that far off that new users register and assume that this just is a good looking forum and therefore not reading the rules? I think not. It's kind of how the whole trashy internet works. I think that a helpful hint would work.

Comment: the word **forum** carries a specific **semantic** that *site,place* do not. That semantic is that discussion is welcome, even encouraged. Especially open ended things with no resolution. The argument that making this distinction clearer will not influence behavior is not the point. It makes the argument of *ignorance* justifies/excuses said behavior invalid.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson to me, forum is just "a place to discuss", PERIOD. meaning and semantic varies from person to person. My point was and remains that this is a non-solution. Okay, people will stop calling Stack a Forum... they'll post their question with "is there a better Q&A site to post this?". Does that change the basic problem that made you open this post? I'd honestly be surprised if you opened this REALLY just because you don't like seeing "forum".

Comment: @shog9 that search was a bit unfair, don't you think? [This is a 100% hit](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22right+forum%22+is%3Aquestion+created%3A30d..)...

Comment: Duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/321702

Comment: @Patrice - you are proving my point, Stack Overflow is **not** a *place to discuss*, that is specifically mentioned in [Don't Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) . *If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.(Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)* Semantics exist for a reason, and people use the word **forum** specifically for the semantic I mentioned, they pick the word *forum* specifically for the **discussion** semantic.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Replace "discuss" with "ask my question". I just had less characters to fill. Doesn't change the fact of the matter that : call it whatever you want, people will still throw thrash into it.  The actual name is SO irrelevant (at least to me). Waste of precious dev time in doing yet another reminder that the users are unlikely to read. This is just my 2 cents about it. Then again I've never been one for pedanticness. That may be why I see little (or no) benefit to this.

Comment: *ask my question* is **not** semantically equivalent to *discuss*. The fact that **you** conflate the terms does not make it a fact or a generalization. If people did not intend the *discussion* semantic they would not use those words, this not pedantic, this is the way language works,specific words are used to provide specific meaning. *male, man, boy* all are similar but have drastically different semantics, that is why they exist otherwise because they are semantically specific versions of *male*.

Comment: Can you see why I said "This is just my 2 cents about it. Then again I've never been one for pedanticness. That may be why I see little (or no) benefit to this"? Because honestly, to me, I can say "cat" to mean dog, and as long as you get what I MEAN, the actual word I used is completely besides my actual point. Because of that, I do not believe this is a Feature Request that'll do more, as I think that other posters who currently use "not sure if this is the right forum", will just change to another sentence to get their crap question answered.

Comment: To me, this is just side-stepping the issue. Instead of fighting so they stop using crap sentences like that ("homework", "interview", "not sure if it's the right forum", "urgent"), we can focus on other ways to prevent those crap questions to appear.... now, I will have to be honest, I am not sure of WHAT can be done. I just really don't see banning the word "forum" being a step in this direction.

Comment: So... You're suggesting we scope this to a phrase that shows up about once a week, @rene?

Comment: @shog9 no, I just wanted you to conclude for yourself exactly what you just did ... my pleasure, you're welcome ... ;)

Comment: "forum" is a perfectly acceptable term for referring to an SE site. Even if you disagree, I don't see how blocking its use in the comment box will really *fix* anything.

Comment: [I know this is old] If they don't read the /ask/advice page presented to them, they probably won't read the warning anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The word "forum" can be used in a completely on-topic way. Even `rene`'s search (when not restricted in time) produces this result: [Incorporating phpBB 3.0 into our HTML page rather than in a whole page for itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982465/)

It's about building a forum.

There are a few other results like that.

---

Most of the people who use the phrase seem to mean "is this the right SE site?", anyway.

SO, like the other SE sites is like a forum in many ways. You most certainly have an opinion (your votes), and you may discuss it with comments (and sometimes even go as far as making your own answer).

Finally, I suspect that having a message like that appear may be especially confusing for people whose first language is not English.